# Telegram bot. Почему не отправляется sendMediaGroup из локального хранилища?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Добрый день ! 
Ребят такая проблема , нужно организовать отправку нескольких фото, или по другому альбома, пользователю. Ниже представлен код который работает только со ссылками на изображения , а при использовании локальных файлов выбивает ошибки.

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI.

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text (message):
    if message.text == "1":
        img1 = '/2/2018-01-02.png'
        img2 = '/2/2018-01-02.png'
        media = [types.InputMediaPhoto(img1, "1"), types.InputMediaPhoto(img2, "2")]
        bot.send_media_group (message.chat.id,media)
```

Ошибка:

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: group send failed"}']
"
2018-01-03 21:02:47,592 (__init__.py:292 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: group send failed"}']"
```

Теперь пробуем предварительно открыть данные изображения , как мы это делаем при отправки обычных фото.

Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text (message):
    if message.text == "1":
        img1 = open('/2/2018-01-02.png','rb')
        img2 = open('/2/2018-01-02.png','rb')
        media = [types.InputMediaPhoto(img1, "1"), types.InputMediaPhoto(img2, "2")]
        bot.send_media_group (message.chat.id,media)
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'BufferedReader' is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема. Я пытаюсь отправить через `requests.post()`:

```
media = [
  {
    'type': 'photo',
    'media': open(image_path, 'rb')
  }
]
args['data']['media'] = JSONEncoder().encode(media)
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+bot_token + "/" + method
r = requests.post(url, **args)
```

Перед отправкой, массивы пропускаю через `JSONEncoder().encode(media)`, но из-за файла Python ругается:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'BufferedReader' is not JSON serializable
```

Если не обрабатывать через `encode()`, то сам Telegram будет ругаться на неверный формат, когда отправляются массивы.

Такое ощущение, что метод `sendMediaGroup` пока не предусматривает нормальную отправку локальных файлов. В качестве "костыльного" решения можно отправить файлы по одному в какую-нибудь "мусорку", чтобы сгенерировались id, а затем передавать эти самые идентификаторы в `sendMediaGroup`.

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/247915)

Comment: @Sublihim в конце ответа есть вполне себе так решние

Answer (score 0):

Вы зачем-то указывали параметр parse_mode = '1', из-за этого сервер не мог обработать запрос

[image: Всё работает]

У меня всё работает, да же с видео

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    print(message.text)
    if message.text == "1":
        img1 = open('sky.png', 'rb')
        img2 = open('logo.png', 'rb')
        img3 = open('result.png', 'rb')
        vid1 = open('video.mp4', 'rb')
        media = [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(img1),
                 telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(img2),
                 telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(img3),
                 telebot.types.InputMediaVideo(vid1)]
        print(media)
        bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media)
```