# Как отправить группу разных медиа telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании телеграмм бота. Во время вызова метода *send_media_group* и передачи ему в качестве аргументов изображение и документ, получаю ошибку, которую не могу исправить.
Пример кода:

```
    img = open(str(pathlib.Path.cwd()) + "\\resources\\images\\" +
               currentTest.questions[indexQuestion].imagePath, 'rb')
    doc = open(str(pathlib.Path.cwd()) + "\\resources\\additionalFiles\\" +
               currentTest.questions[indexQuestion].filePath, 'rb')
    media = [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(img), telebot.types.InputMediaDocument(doc)]
    msg = bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media)
```

Ошибка:

```
2022-11-25 17:29:36,167 (__init__.py:986 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: document can't be mixed with other media types"
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: document can't be mixed with other media types
```

Comment: Так он для этого и создан, что бы отправлять разные типы.

Comment: Вот в этом вопросе есть ответ, где при помощи send_media_group отправляются разные группы медиа, в их случае фото и видео.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766263/telegram-bot-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-sendmediagroup-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%b0#new-answer?newreg=360e2418197a4c01b470cee6cd3341cc